# Adding Profiling and Logging perspective to Eclipse on RedHat

Tags: java, eclipse, profile, eclipse-tptp

I am trying to set up Eclipse so I can profile a Java program using the TPTP profiler. I have downloaded and unzipped all the `.zip` files that I believe I need, but Eclipse still does not provide a "Profiling and Logging" perspective. What more must I do to get this perspective? Is there perhaps a configuration file I must edit?

- I'm using Red Hat RHEL5, and thus Eclipse 3.2.0, TPTP 4.2.0.2.
- The `Window > Open Perspective > Other...` dialog-box does not list the "Profiling and Logging" perspective.
- The `Help > About Eclipse Platform > Plug-in Details` window lists numerous pacakges in the `org.eclipse.tptp` name-space, including `org.eclipse.tptp.platform.lta` and `org.eclipse.tptp.trace`. Which plug-in is responsible for providing the perspective?
- The `Window > Preferences...` dialog does not have an entry for "Profiling and Logging".

Comment: Is there a reason you used the `.zip` download instead of the built in Eclipse installer with the TPTP update site? I assume Eclipses as old as 3.2 still have the `Help -> Install New Software` menu item. If not, is something keeping you from using a version of Eclipse that isn't 4 years old?

Comment: @Kane: 3.2 has a dialog `Help > Software Updates > Find and Install...`, but it was defeated (I think) by our HTTP proxy. I'm using 3.2 because that is the RHEL 5 supplied version.

Comment: If 3.2 (I have 3.7 and I don't remember the old interface all that well) has an "archive" option, it may be better to try and install from a local archive than handling the installation manually. Since you say your proxy might be a problem, I wonder if the plugin tried to get some dependencies that the proxy blocked, and installing manually didn't include those dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I tried again to use `Help > Software Updates > Find and Install...` to have Eclipse download and install the plug-ins itself. This time with more success, but still no joy. Significantly it tries to update some parts of the Eclipse core. That installation failed because the `/usr/shar/eclipse` files (installed by the eclipse RPM from Red Hat) are owned by `root` rather than myself. It seems therefore that, despite what the release notes say, TPTP requires a fixed version of Eclipse 3.2. I guess the moral of this story is to forget about trying to use the Eclipse RPM, and instead down-load and install it in your home directory.

Comment: For other people, note that newer versions of Eclipse are not compatible with TPTP, you should install instead "JVM Monitor"

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the installation, with the newer versions of Eclipse, `TPTP` does not work. You need JVM Monitor.

1. **Installation**: `Help > Eclipse Marketplace > JVM Monitor`
2. **Activation**: `Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other > Java Monitor`

While this may be irrelevant because the OP's issue was apparently caused by a permissions issue, it may be helpful to those googling in the future.