# How to add Profiling And Logging perspective to Eclipse Luna?

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, performance-testing, eclipse-luna

I am trying to follow these instructions

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html

and eventually was led to this unresolved question:

[Adding Profiling and Logging perspective to Eclipse on RedHat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229598/adding-profiling-and-logging-perspective-to-eclipse-on-redhat)

I'm actually using Windows 7, but the issue is similar to the one reported above for Redhat.

How to add Profiling And Logging perspective to Eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Profiling and Logging" perspective is part if the [Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm) which is in archive mode as of Eclipse Helios, and is not included in later distributions of Eclipse.

Alternatives are the [JVM Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786655/274350) or [JProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749952/274350) plugins.